# What teachings do all Catholic schools share?

Tags: doctrine

Among the many schools and traditions, what core teachings are shared by all Catholics?

Comment: Do you mean all members of the Roman Catholic church? Because that constitutes the vast majority of "Catholics". And they have the same core teachings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Catechism of the Catholic Church](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM) would be a close match to what you want.

Here's a brief outline of the contents:

- PROLOGUE
- PART ONE: THE PROFESSION OF FAITH

  - SECTION ONE "I BELIEVE" - "WE BELIEVE"

    - CHAPTER ONE MAN'S CAPACITY FOR GOD
    - CHAPTER TWO GOD COMES TO MEET MAN
    - CHAPTER THREE MAN'S RESPONSE TO GOD
  - SECTION TWO I. THE CREEDS

    - CHAPTER ONE I BELIEVE IN GOD THE FATHER
    - CHAPTER TWO I BELIEVE IN JESUS CHRIST, THE ONLY SON OF GOD
    - CHAPTER THREE I BELIEVE IN THE HOLY SPIRIT
- PART TWO: THE CELEBRATION OF THE CHRISTIAN MYSTERY

  - SECTION ONE THE SACRAMENTAL ECONOMY

    - CHAPTER ONE THE PASCHAL MYSTERY IN THE AGE OF THE CHURCH
    - CHAPTER TWO THE SACRAMENTAL CELEBRATION OF THE PASCHAL MYSTERY
  - SECTION TWO THE SEVEN SACRAMENTS OF THE CHURCH

    - CHAPTER ONE THE SACRAMENTS OF CHRISTIAN INITIATION
    - CHAPTER TWO THE SACRAMENTS OF HEALING
    - CHAPTER THREE THE SACRAMENTS AT THE SERVICE OF COMMUNION
    - CHAPTER FOUR OTHER LITURGICAL CELEBRATIONS
- PART THREE: LIFE IN CHRIST

  - SECTION ONE MAN'S VOCATION LIFE IN THE SPIRIT

    - CHAPTER ONE THE DIGNITY OF THE HUMAN PERSON
    - CHAPTER TWO THE HUMAN COMMUNION
    - CHAPTER THREE GOD'S SALVATION: LAW AND GRACE
  - SECTION TWO THE TEN COMMANDMENTS

    - CHAPTER ONE YOU SHALL LOVE THE LORD YOUR GOD WITH ALL YOUR HEART, AND WITH ALL YOUR SOUL, AND WITH ALL YOUR MIND
    - CHAPTER TWO YOU SHALL LOVE YOUR NEIGHBOR AS YOURSELF
      PART FOUR: CHRISTIAN PRAYER
  - SECTION ONE PRAYER IN THE CHRISTIAN LIFE

    - CHAPTER ONE THE REVELATION OF PRAYER - THE UNIVERSAL CALL TO PRAYER
    - CHAPTER TWO THE TRADITION OF PRAYER
    - CHAPTER THREE THE LIFE OF PRAYER
  - SECTION TWO THE LORD'S PRAYER

Answer (score 0):

**What teachings do all Catholic schools share?**

The fundamental aim of of Catholic Schools is to teach the assimilation of objective values, and, when this is undertaken for an apostolic purpose, it does not stop at an integration of faith and culture but leads the pupil on to a personal integration of faith and life.

Beyond the academics, the Catholic school must teach its pupils to grow in conformity of the Gospels!

> **Integration of faith and life**
>
> 44. The fundamental aim of teaching is the assimilation of objective values, and, when this is undertaken for an apostolic purpose, it does not stop at an integration of faith and culture but leads the pupil on to a personal integration of faith and life.
> 45. The Catholic school has as its specific duty the complete Christian formation of its pupils, and this task is of special significance today because of the inadequacy of the family and society. It knows that this integration of faith and life is part of a life-long process of conversion until the pupil becomes what God wishes him to be. Young people have to be taught to share their personal lives with God. They are to overcome their individualism and discover, in the light of faith, their specific vocation to live responsibly in a community with others. The very pattern of the Christian life draws them to commit themselves to serve God in their brethren and to make the world a better place for man to live in.
> 46. **The Catholic school should teach its pupils to discern in the voice of the universe the Creator Whom it reveals and, in the conquests of science, to know God and man better. In the daily life of the school, the pupil should learn that he is called to be a living witness to God's love for men by the way he acts, and that he is part of that salvation history which has Christ, the Saviour of the world, as its goal.**
> 47. Being aware that Baptism by itself does not make a Christian - living and acting in conformity with the Gospel is necessary - the Catholic school tries to create within its walls a climate in which the pupil's faith will gradually mature and enable him to assume the responsibility placed on him by Baptism. It will give pride of place in the education it provides through Christian Doctrine to the gradual formation of conscience in fundamental, permanent virtues - above all the theological virtues, and charity in particular, which is, so to speak, the life-giving spirit which transforms a man of virtue into a man of Christ. Christ, therefore, is the teaching-centre, the Model on Whom the Christian shapes his life. In Him the Catholic school differs from all others which limit themselves to forming men. Its task is to form Christian men, and, by its teaching and witness, show non-Christians something of the mystery of Christ Who surpasses all human understanding.
> 48. The Catholic school will work closely with other Christian bodies (the family, the parish and Christian community, youth associations, etc.). But one must not overlook many other spheres of activity in society which are sources of information and in their various ways have an educational influence. Alongside this so-called " parallel school ", the school proper is an active force through the systematic formation of the pupils' critical faculties to bring them to a measure of self control and the ability to choose freely and conscientiously in the face of what is offered by the organs of social communication. They must be taught to subject these things to a critical and personal analysis, take what is good, and integrate it into their Christian human culture. - [The Catholic School](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccatheduc/documents/rc_con_ccatheduc_doc_19770319_catholic-school_en.html)